# Understanding Wait times With Admin Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to understand wait times with admin-ajax.php on wordpress with WooCommerce. I know wait time is the time the browser resolves the host name. My question is why does Pingdom show a long wait time but a short load time. Is this due to caching by W3 Total Cache? 
[image: Image 01]
[image: Image 01]